# prevent user closing a HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

Using vbscript in a HTA

Aim: To prevent a user closing the HTA (except by my custom button or by using windows taskmanager)

As i understand from various webpages; You cannot prevent the HTA from closing when the close button is clicked in the HTA SYSMENU. Therefore my solution is to prevent the user from clicking close in the first place.

First up is to disable the system menu:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION SYSMENU="no" />
```

nb. I will replace the system menu with a custom one - any links to a good guide for this would be appreciated.

Next prevent keyboard shortcuts alt+f4, f5, or escape as follows:

```
Function Document_onKeyDown()

    Dim alt
    alt = window.event.altKey
    Select Case window.event.keyCode
        Case 27,116
            window.event.keyCode = 0
            window.event.cancelBubble = true
            Document_onKeyDown = False
        Case 115
            If alt Then
                window.event.keyCode = 0
                window.event.cancelBubble = true
                Document_onKeyDown = False
            End If
        Case Else
            Document_onKeyDown = True
    End Select

End Function
```

Finally I want to prevent the user using the windows taskbar context menu for my HTA app.

How can I prevent the user from seeing a context menu by right clicking my HTA?

nb. The HTA window cannot be full screen

Answer (score 3):

Don't mess with a user's options to close your application. It's not up to you to decide how a user should work. Instead add a cleanup procedure where you do all the "on close" tasks and then call it on the [`beforeunload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
        ID="oHTA"
        APPLICATIONNAME="sample"
    />
    
    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub cleanup
        'clean up stuff here
        End Sub
    </script>
</head>

<body onbeforeunload="cleanup">
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would normally not care how a user closes an app. However in this case; if a user closes the hta while still waiting for WShell.Run operation to complete mshta.exe process will not terminate. Ideally in onBeforeUnload I would either cancel the attempt to close whilst WShell.Run is ongoing (however this functionality doesnt seem to work) or I would wait for WShell.Run to complete and then close (also doesnt seem to work)

Comment: @Danaldo Why do you need to wait for `WShell.Run` in the first place? Run the external process asynchronously, so it doesn't matter whether the HTA is terminated or not. If other code in your HTA depends on the completion of the external program, you could use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for tracking its status. It's a little more complicated than the `Run` method, but most likely a cleaner solution.

Comment: using WMI instead of wshell.run - If I was to run a second script how can i view the return code set with WScript.Quit? If it is not possible I know I could write a value to a temporary file and read this file when WMI indicates that the script has completed. However would be better if the WMI object has a facility to give you a return code. Preferably using the processID...

Comment: @Danaldo An external VBScript could set a variable in the [volatile environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to indicate its status. Or you could simply integrate the script code into the HTA and avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: The script code was initially in the HTA. I extracted the script because it was long and as a HTA is single threaded it caused the UI to be unresponsive. As it is a background script there is no need for the HTA to wait for completion. However when the script completes the HTA needs the result. Does the creation of a volatile environment variable depend on the user priveleges, or because its only valid for a single log-on session mean that it is independent of user rights?

Comment: @Danaldo Any user can create a volatile variable. It's tied to their session and is automatically destroyed when the user logs off.

Answer (score 1):

With regards:

> How can I prevent the user from seeing a context menu by right clicking my HTA?

```
<HTA:APPLICATION contextMenu="no">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTA:APPLICATION showintaskbar="no">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That option alone will not be enough. See other answers. But, in general, please follow the good advice given below: "Don't mess with a user's options to close your application".